# Does this parable of Ramakrishna Paramahamsa have a scriptural basis?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, ramakrishna

http://www.ramakrishnamath.in/gospel/

> **SANKARACHARYA AND HIS FOOLISH DISCIPLE**
>
> ---
>
> THE great Sankaracharya had a foolish disciple who used to imitate his
>   Master in all matters. Sankara uttered ‘Sivoham’ (I am Siva); the
>   disciple also repeated “Sivoham‟. To correct his disciple’s folly,
>   Sankara one day, while passing by a smithy, took a potful of molten
>   iron and swallowed it; and he asked that disciple also to do the same.
>   Of course, the disciple could not imitate this act of his Master, and
>   thence forward he left oil saying “Sivoham‟."

Comment: Add your question in the body also. Question should not be asked only in the title. It is only for introduction. There should be detailed question in the body.

Comment: How can it have a scriptural basis? It is an incident from the life of Adi Sankara and His biographies are not considered as scriptures!